# Choosing voltage divider resistor values

Tags: thevenin

[image]

Above is the circuit in question.

R1 and R2 forms a voltage divider to supply desired current for the load.

On the left side there is the original circuit and on the right side its Thevenin equivalent.

Lets say the ideal supply voltage is known and we want 0.01A current through our load RL which is 100 ohm.

So we can write the given and desired as:

Vcc = 5V

Ith = 0.01A

RL = 100 ohm (load resistance)

Here we can employ the Kirchhoff's law for the Thevenized circuit as:

Vth = Ith*Rth + Ith*RL

Vth - 1 = Ith*Rth

5*R2/(R1+R2) - 1 = 0.01 * R1*R2/(R1+R2)

R1 = 400*R2/(R2+100)

So now we have a relationship between R1 and R2.

For example:

if R2 = 100ohm then R1 = 200 ohm

if R2 = 10k ohm then R1 = 396 ohm

So far so good. If we plot R1 versus R2 for 1 to 100ohm and 1 to 10kohm we obtain the following plots:

[image]

[image]

It seems like for R2 at around 10k, R1 goes to a limit like 400ohm.

I think one can choose here like 400ohm for R1 and any resistor above 10k for R2.

I also noticed if R1 and R2 is low resistances such as R2 = 100ohm then R1 = 200 ohm, the current flowing through R1 and R2 is much higher.

### Here is my question:

Does that mean we should avoid choosing low resistors for R1 R2 just not to drive more current?

And if so, what is the rule of thumb if we only know the exact value of RL and the relation R1 = 400*R2/(R2+100) ?

I mean is there a rule of thumb between RL and Rth or RL and R2? Would you have a rule of thumb between RL and Rth or RL and R2?

Comment: It generally means that we should avoid voltage dividers for supplying voltages in most cases.

Comment: Or in other words: You should only use such a voltage divider when the current you draw from it is **significantly** smaller than the current flowing through the voltage divider. If this does not bring a solution, a voltage buffering circuit is needed.

Comment: why would one want the current through voltage divider greater?

Comment: If R1 and R2 too small then what u say happens but if I choose them greater like in my question I dont waste current and power to obtain same load current. I didnt get what u mean

Comment: my aim is not to supply voltage here. to supply a desired current

Comment: @user16307: You can't have one without the other.

Comment: yes but i think they think i want to drive minimum current

Comment: btw what they say is very different than what u say. they say voltage divider current must be much greater than load current which i didnt get

Comment: @user16307: A voltage divider is usually used to set a reference voltage,  and if its load (of necessity being in parallel with either R1 or R2) is too great, the resistance of the parallel pair will change the reference voltage too much.  In your case, the use of a voltage divider is wrong and R2 should be eliminated.

Comment: I understand the part that R2 is not necessary. But you also say "if its load too great" The load is 100 ohm here what do you mean? why would R1 and R2 change ref voltage?

Comment: Please reply to a comment by preceding it with the commenter's name, like I have to your replies That way, yourreply goes directly to their inbox and they don't have to come back here to see whether you replied.

Comment: @EMFields im writing to u the rest already do not reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation you outline, the rule of thumb is to eliminate R2 and determine the value of the voltage required at the \$ R1Rl \$ junction by using Ohm's law:

$$ E_{J} = IR = 0.01A \times 100\Omega = 1 \text{volt} $$

Since the current in a series circuit is everywhere the same, the 0.01 amperes through the load resistor must also go through R1.

Then since the supply voltage, Vcc, is 5 volts and you want the motor to see 1 volt, Ohm's law dictates that the value of R1 **must** be:

$$R1 = \frac{Vcc -  V_{J}}{I} -\frac{4V}{0.01A} = 400 \text{ohms}  $$

Comment: So it means R2 will be huge as possible to avoid driving extra current right? So you take R2 as if it is open which corresponds a huge resistor. Did I get u right?

Comment: or do you mean we should remove R2 from the circuit?

Comment: @user16307:  Removing R2 from the circuit will make it as huge as possible, yes?

Comment: yes i got that point, i just didnt get why this voltage dvider wokld only be useful if load current is too low. which application they meant they say voltage divider should have huge current comparing to load current

Comment: @user16307; Usually, a voltage divider does have a huge current compared to the load, but that's in applications when the output of the voltage divider is being used as a reference voltage for the  high input resistance devices like comparators, which is not your application at all.  What you seem to be having trouble with is that R1 and RL are **already** a voltage divider,  and all the addition of R2 does, since it's  in parallel with RL, is make it look, to R1, that RL is less than 100 ohms, messing up the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If your load shouldn't change its electrical consumption, then you may use the confluent divider in which the R2 is going to infinity and R1 is about 400 Ohm. So the 400Ohm may be included in resistance of your power source (see the full Ohm's law).
But if no - if your load's current may have in a peak the 0,15A or 0,02A (whatewer how much - but higher than 0,01), then your load will get a lack of power, because of 400Ohm restrictor (R1):

100Ohm * 0,01A = 1V.
1V / 0,02A = 50 Ohm.
So at pike the resistance of your load is 50Ohm.
400Ohm + 50Ohm = 450 Ohm.
5V / 450Ohm = 0, 0111A.
Even your load has ability to reduce its resistance to be equal a zero, the maximum possible current is
5V / 400 Ohm = 0,0125A.
what is not enough for your load.
And for this case the empiric rule about voltage divider is a good advice: current of a R2 must be higher in 10 times or more than a current of your load you want to use with divider. In this case the equivalent resistance of R2&RL will stay in a narrow diapason and will not strongly affect the equivalent current of a divider.